# Amazon Kinesis Video GetMedia/PutMedia

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

I used python 3.6 and I want to post video stream to aws kinesis with API.
I used python aws client to create stream and `GetDataEndPoint` but when I want to post my data with my custom request (`PutMedia` doesn't include in python client actually), I get an error `Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized`.

I've follow the api doc of aws kinesis video media [PutMedia](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_dataplane_PutMedia.html#API_dataplane_PutMedia_Errors) and [GetMedia](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/API_dataplane_GetMedia.html).

So I start by getting endpoint with `GetDataEndPoint` with [client method](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/kinesisvideo.html#KinesisVideo.Client.get_data_endpoint):

```
response = client.get_data_endpoint(  # aws client method
    StreamName=STREAM_NAME,
    APIName='PUT_MEDIA'
)
end_point = response['DataEndpoint'] # https://s-EXAMPLE.kinesisvideo.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
```

and I post my data at this url:

```
headers = {
    "x-amzn-stream-arn": STREAM_ARN,
    "x-amzn-fragment-timecode-type": "ABSOLUTE",
    "x-amzn-producer-start-timestamp": start_tmstp
}
# Sign header...
response = requests.post(end_point, data=data, headers=headers)  # 403 - Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized
```

So I don't understand why I get this error... I've found this [troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-api-name-auth) on aws doc. But they say we must specify ApiName parameter. What I do...

> This error might occur if the endpoint is not properly specified. When you are getting the endpoint, be sure to include the following parameter in the GetDataEndpoint call, depending on the API to be called:

I'm also wondering if the `GetMedia` method is actually implemented in client as they say [here](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/kinesis-video-media.html#KinesisVideoMedia.Client.get_media) because when I debug this method, client don't call `GetDataEndPoint` and so make request at `https://kinesisvideo.region.amazonaws.com` insteed of `https://ID_EXAMPLE.kinesisvideo.region.amazonaws.com`. So method get error `Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized` as explained in [troubleshooting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/troubleshooting.html#troubleshooting-api-name-auth)

Comment: I am stuck at the same thing, can you share the full code of how to send the media to using PutMedia with python??

Comment: I made a piece of code working: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59551573/362754

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is because you're probably providing the endpoint without the "action" that in your case would be `putMedia`.

Try to append `/putMedia` to your endpoint and don't forget to specify the `"content-type": "application/json"` header.

Btw you have also to generate the [v4 signatures](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html) for your request. You can use a lib or follow this [python guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html) to do it.

Comment: Noticed an [issue on github](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-producer-sdk-java/issues/26) says that the payload hash should be excluded from the v4 signature.

Comment: Can you share the full code example? Thank you very much anyway!

Comment: Actually I asked for samples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481174/amazon-aws-kinesis-video-boto-getmedia-putmedia . Can you put an answer there?