# Amazon AWS Kinesis Video Boto GetMedia/PutMedia

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis

Does anybody know of a complete sample as to how to send video to a kinesis video stream, using boto3 sdk?

This question was asked initially for both both GetMedia and PutMedia. Now I have got this sample code for the GetMedia part:

```
client = boto3.client('kinesisvideo')
response = client.get_data_endpoint(
    StreamName='my-test-stream',
    APIName='GET_MEDIA'
)
print(response)
endpoint = response.get('DataEndpoint', None)
print("endpoint %s" % endpoint)

if endpoint is not None:
    client2 = boto3.client('kinesis-video-media', endpoint_url=endpoint)
    response = client2.get_media(
        StreamName='my-test-stream',
        StartSelector={
            'StartSelectorType': 'EARLIEST',
        }
    )
    print(response)

    stream = response['Payload'] # botocore.response.StreamingBody object
    while True:
            ret, frame = stream.read()
            print(" stream type ret %s frame %s" % (type(ret), type(frame)))
```

How do you to the PutMedia? From a previous post "[Amazon Kinesis Video GetMedia/PutMedia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713393/amazon-kinesis-video-getmedia-putmedia)", it looks like you have to construct your own url request for a PutMedia. Is that the case? If it is, can someone share a complete sample?

Comment: Thnaks@minghua, This works well. In my case, I want to save the stream. Can you please help me with this if you know how to store stream.

Comment: @B.Kanani , Have you tested this piece of code recently? Since you said it "works well". Wonder whether you saw the "fragment timestamp missing" issue that Nikhil commented about last year.

Comment: As to your question of "save stream", not sure what is your context. It should be asked as a separate question, and you should provide more details there.

Answer (score 8):

The code below works.

The code is largely derived from a [previous post How to Implement Amazon Kinesis PutMedia Method using PYTHON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51991401/how-to-implement-amazon-kinesis-putmedia-method-using-python) and [Amazon Kinesis Video PutMedia Using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033203/amazon-kinesis-video-putmedia-using-python). Some of the changes are from monitoring how the kinesis video stream c-producer 2.0.2 works.

The same pair of keys are set twice: once in the way for boto, another by the two special environment variables at the beginning of the code.

```
your_env_access_key_var = 'AWS_KVS_USER_ACCESS_KEY'
your_env_secret_key_var = 'AWS_KVS_USER_SECRET_KEY'
your_stream_name = 'my-video-stream-test'

def get_endpoint_boto():
    import boto3

    client = boto3.client('kinesisvideo')
    response = client.get_data_endpoint(
        StreamName=your_stream_name,
        APIName='PUT_MEDIA'
    )
    pp.pprint(response)
    endpoint = response.get('DataEndpoint', None)
    print("endpoint %s" % endpoint)
    if endpoint is None:
        raise Exception("endpoint none")
    return endpoint

def sign(key, msg):
    return hmac.new(key, msg.encode("utf-8"), hashlib.sha256).digest()

def get_signature_key(key, date_stamp, regionName, serviceName):
    kDate = sign(('AWS4' + key).encode('utf-8'), date_stamp)
    kRegion = sign(kDate, regionName)
    kService = sign(kRegion, serviceName)
    kSigning = sign(kService, 'aws4_request')
    return kSigning

def get_host_from_endpoint(endpoint):
    # u'https://s-123abc78.kinesisvideo.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
    if not endpoint.startswith('https://'):
        return None
    retv = endpoint[len('https://'):]
    return str(retv)

def get_region_from_endpoint(endpoint):
    # u'https://s-123abc78.kinesisvideo.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'
    if not endpoint.startswith('https://'):
        return None
    retv = endpoint[len('https://'):].split('.')[2]
    return str(retv)


class gen_request_parameters:
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = ''
        if True:
            localfile = '6-step_example.webm.360p.webm' # upload ok
            #localfile = 'big-buck-bunny_trailer.webm' # error fragment duration over limit
            with open(localfile, 'rb') as image:
                request_parameters = image.read()
                self._data = request_parameters
        self._pointer = 0
        self._size = len(self._data)
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        if self._pointer >= self._size:
            raise StopIteration  # signals "the end"
        left = self._size - self._pointer
        chunksz = 16000
        if left < 16000:
            chunksz = left
        pointer_start = self._pointer
        self._pointer += chunksz
        print("Data: chunk size %d" % chunksz)
        return self._data[pointer_start:self._pointer]


# ************* REQUEST VALUES *************
endpoint = get_endpoint_boto()

method = 'POST'
service = 'kinesisvideo'
host = get_host_from_endpoint(endpoint)
region = get_region_from_endpoint(endpoint)
##endpoint = 'https://**<the endpoint you get with get_data_endpoint>**/PutMedia'

endpoint += '/putMedia'

# POST requests use a content type header. For DynamoDB,
# the content is JSON.
content_type = 'application/json'
start_tmstp = repr(time.time())

# Read AWS access key from env. variables or configuration file. Best practice is NOT
# to embed credentials in code.
access_key = None # '*************************'
secret_key = None # '*************************'
while True: # scope
    k = os.getenv(your_env_access_key_var)
    if k is not None and type(k) is str and k.startswith('AKIA5'):
        access_key = k
    k = os.getenv(your_env_secret_key_var)
    if k is not None and type(k) is str and len(k) > 4:
        secret_key = k
    break # scope
if access_key is None or secret_key is None:
    print('No access key is available.')
    sys.exit()

# Create a date for headers and the credential string
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
amz_date = t.strftime('%Y%m%dT%H%M%SZ')
date_stamp = t.strftime('%Y%m%d')  # Date w/o time, used in credential scope

# ************* TASK 1: CREATE A CANONICAL REQUEST *************
# http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-canonical-request.html

# Step 1 is to define the verb (GET, POST, etc.)--already done.

# Step 2: Create canonical URI--the part of the URI from domain to query
# string (use '/' if no path)
##canonical_uri = '/'
canonical_uri = '/putMedia' #endpoint[len('https://'):]

## Step 3: Create the canonical query string. In this example, request
# parameters are passed in the body of the request and the query string
# is blank.
canonical_querystring = ''

# Step 4: Create the canonical headers. Header names must be trimmed
# and lowercase, and sorted in code point order from low to high.
# Note that there is a trailing \n.
#'host:' + host + '\n' +
canonical_headers = ''
#canonical_headers += 'Accept: */*\r\n'
canonical_headers += 'connection:keep-alive\n'
canonical_headers += 'content-type:application/json\n'
canonical_headers += 'host:' + host + '\n'
canonical_headers += 'transfer-encoding:chunked\n'
#canonical_headers += 'x-amz-content-sha256: ' + 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD' + '\r\n'
canonical_headers += 'user-agent:AWS-SDK-KVS/2.0.2 GCC/7.4.0 Linux/4.15.0-46-generic x86_64\n'
canonical_headers += 'x-amz-date:' + amz_date + '\n'
canonical_headers += 'x-amzn-fragment-acknowledgment-required:1\n'
canonical_headers += 'x-amzn-fragment-timecode-type:ABSOLUTE\n'
canonical_headers += 'x-amzn-producer-start-timestamp:' + start_tmstp + '\n'
canonical_headers += 'x-amzn-stream-name:' + your_stream_name + '\n'

# Step 5: Create the list of signed headers. This lists the headers
# in the canonical_headers list, delimited with ";" and in alpha order.
# Note: The request can include any headers; canonical_headers and
# signed_headers include those that you want to be included in the
# hash of the request. "Host" and "x-amz-date" are always required.
# For DynamoDB, content-type and x-amz-target are also required.
#
#in original sample  after x-amz-date :  + 'x-amz-target;'
signed_headers = 'connection;content-type;host;transfer-encoding;user-agent;'
signed_headers += 'x-amz-date;x-amzn-fragment-acknowledgment-required;'
signed_headers += 'x-amzn-fragment-timecode-type;x-amzn-producer-start-timestamp;x-amzn-stream-name'

# Step 6: Create payload hash. In this example, the payload (body of
# the request) contains the request parameters.

# Step 7: Combine elements to create canonical request
canonical_request = method + '\n' + canonical_uri + '\n' + canonical_querystring + '\n' + canonical_headers + '\n' + signed_headers
canonical_request += '\n'
canonical_request += hashlib.sha256(''.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# ************* TASK 2: CREATE THE STRING TO SIGN*************
# Match the algorithm to the hashing algorithm you use, either SHA-1 or
# SHA-256 (recommended)
algorithm = 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'
credential_scope = date_stamp + '/' + region + '/' + service + '/' + 'aws4_request'
string_to_sign = algorithm + '\n' + amz_date + '\n' + credential_scope + '\n' + hashlib.sha256(
    canonical_request.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()

# ************* TASK 3: CALCULATE THE SIGNATURE *************
# Create the signing key using the function defined above.
signing_key = get_signature_key(secret_key, date_stamp, region, service)

# Sign the string_to_sign using the signing_key
signature = hmac.new(signing_key, (string_to_sign).encode('utf-8'),
                     hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()

# ************* TASK 4: ADD SIGNING INFORMATION TO THE REQUEST *************
# Put the signature information in a header named Authorization.
authorization_header = algorithm + ' ' + 'Credential=' + access_key + '/' + credential_scope + ', '
authorization_header += 'SignedHeaders=' + signed_headers + ', ' + 'Signature=' + signature

# # Python note: The 'host' header is added automatically by the Python 'requests' library.
headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Authorization': authorization_header,
    'connection': 'keep-alive',
    'content-type': content_type,
    #'host': host,
    'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
    # 'x-amz-content-sha256': 'UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD',
    'user-agent': 'AWS-SDK-KVS/2.0.2 GCC/7.4.0 Linux/4.15.0-46-generic x86_64',
    'x-amz-date': amz_date,
    'x-amzn-fragment-acknowledgment-required': '1',
    'x-amzn-fragment-timecode-type': 'ABSOLUTE',
    'x-amzn-producer-start-timestamp': start_tmstp,
    'x-amzn-stream-name': your_stream_name,
    'Expect': '100-continue'
}

# ************* SEND THE REQUEST *************
print('\nBEGIN REQUEST++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print('Request URL = ' + endpoint)

r = requests.post(endpoint, data=gen_request_parameters(), headers=headers)

print('\nRESPONSE++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++')
print('Response code: %d\n' % r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: I think u have done a lot of research on it. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for me. Fragment timestamp is missing in your request

Comment: Do you mean it needs a further fix to include the "fragment timestamp"? It worked when I tested to the server at us-east-2.

Comment: @minghua Just 2 questions, this works if there is a file in the directory with name: 6-step_example.webm.360p.webm? also pp.print in def get_endpoint_boto(): ?

Comment: @Manza, yes that's correct. but the file were downloaded from the internet. it cannot guarantee any other file using the same name will work. look back at the code again, the comment says another file did not work.

Comment: For anyone else encountering a `404 UnknownOperationException`, notice that it is `POST` and not a `PUT`, despite the endpoint name...